# Cannot use the "not equal" operator when querying for a collection in AngularFire

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am trying to pull a collection from Firebase that is not associated to the user. So far, I've successfully queried for the user's collection, but I can't seem to get the collection that is not associated with the user using the `!=` operator.

Here's my code:

```
  // Does not work!
  eventCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Event> = this.angularFirestore.collection("events", ref =>
    ref.where("uid", "!=", this.firebaseAuth.auth.currentUser.uid)
  );
  eventCollection$: Observable<Event[]> = this.eventCollection.valueChanges();

  // Works!
  myCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Event> = this.angularFirestore.collection("events", ref =>
    ref.where("uid", "==", this.firebaseAuth.auth.currentUser.uid)
  );
  myCollection$: Observable<Event[]> = this.myCollection.valueChanges();
```

The error that's thrown is:

```
ERROR in src/app/event/events.service.ts(35,22): error TS2345: Argument of type '"!"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WhereFilterOp'.
```

I tried looking for a logical operator that corresponds to `!=`, but can't seem to find it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Firestore [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries):

> Queries with a != clause. In this case, you should split the query into a greater-than query and a less-than query. For example, although the query clause where("age", "!=", "30") is not supported, you can get the same result set by combining two queries, one with the clause where("age", "<", "30") and one with the clause where("age", ">", 30).

So you must compare both '<' and '>' condition

```js
eventCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Event> = 
  this.angularFirestore.collection("events", ref =>
    ref.where("uid", ">", this.firebaseAuth.auth.currentUser.uid)
       .where("uid", "<", this.firebaseAuth.auth.currentUser.uid)
  );
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!

Comment: How does this work when comparing `String` type auth uids?

Comment: does this not do && instead of || ?

Comment: @ebg11 i'm thinking the same. Has anyone tried this? In my understanding this produces an empty result.

Comment: tried it, it doesnt work. How can this be the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

[It looks like](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/2f17ba02a3a139678b849cd53b2199156e5bc6d1/packages/firebase/index.d.ts#L1608) there is no `!=` operator.  I'm not familiar with Firebase, but perhaps you could do separate queries for `<` and `>` and combine the results?  Or since you also want the equal results, just do one query without the `where` and separate the equal and unequal results yourself?